# How to change background color of datepicker form in Materialize design using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I'm using date picker in [materialize design](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) and I'm trying to change background-color using jQuery.

[Materialize Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQP5v.png)

I tried with this line and it doesn't work

```
$(".picker__weekday-display").css("color", "#FF0F0F", "important");
```

I need to use JavaScript because I have to change my color dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you added the javascript in your $(document).ready? If the calendar was not initialize it will not find your class.

Comment: OMG..Im so noob..
My line work perfecly .. I jsut didn't put it at the right place!
Thx

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of `$.css()` is incorrect - and you'll also need to use `background` or `background-color` instead of `color`.

You can write

```
$(".picker__weekday-display").css("background-color", "#FF0F0F !important")
```

or

```
$(".picker__weekday-display").css({"background-color": "#FF0F0F !important"})
```

See the API:

http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value

However, the API also states:

> Note: .css() ignores !important declarations. So, the statement $( "p" ).css( "color", "red !important" ) does not turn the color of all paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.

So you might be better off to add a class instead:

```
$(".picker__weekday-display").addClass("my-class");
```

**CSS:**

```
.my-class {
  background-color: #FF0F0F !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried this:
 $(".picker__date-display").css({ "background-color": "#ff00ff !important" })

still not work :(

But I change my header color with this:
 $(".customColor").css("background-color", "#ff00ff") 

And it work perfectly, I don't understand why it doesn't work with materialize datepicker :S

Comment: Have you tried to use a CSS class instead? It's important you achieve a higher `CSS specifity` than the existing modifier. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity - you can see the applied/overwritten styles in your browser's console.

Comment: Yeah I tried it like this:
$(".picker__date-display").addClass(".customColor")

.customColor is the color of my header

still not working

If I change it in my css file, it work perfectly, but I have to change it dynamically so I have to do it with jQuery

Comment: The dot `.` must only be added to the stylesheet (see my example above). You must not add the dot in the `addClass()` function:  `$(".picker__date-display").addClass("customColor")`. And as I also said, you must make sure to achieve a higher CSS specifity (with your stylesheet selector) than other existing background color modifications.

Comment: Thx for your help my first line work perfecly, it was just not at the right place

Answer (score 0):

`color` is foreground (text) color.  Use `backgroundColor`.

Comment: I copy the wrong line :S My bad is use background-color